# Formula re-evaluation issues in MS Excel 2010 Beta

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

This has only started happening recently, where I have say a list of values:

```
     A  B  C
     _  _  _
1|   1  4  5  [=sum(A1,B1)]

2|   2  5

3|   3  6
```

I have my formula in cell C1 [enclosed in square brakcs for visualisation], and I want to duplicate it down the C column.  So I select the cell, click the little black square bottom right of the cell, and drag it down.

The result is this

```
     A  B  C
     _  _  _
1|   1  4  5  [=sum(A1,B1)]

2|   2  5  5  [=sum(A2,B2)]

3|   3  6  5  [=sum(A2,B2)]
```

The sums don't actually evaluate until I go into each one individually, and click the formula bar, and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I don't want to have to do this for hundreds of rows.

Is there a 'Re-evaluate all Formulas' button? Like in Word, you can re-evaluate all items in a Table of Contents...

Comment: this "little black square" is called **fill handle** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[F9]  - recalculates your workbook (and every function)

You might also go to options and check "calculations" tab (or similar, I don't have 2010 in front of me) and look for **automatic** / **manual** calculation method.

> F9
>
> Calculates all worksheets in all open
>   workbooks.
>
> SHIFT+F9 calculates the active
>   worksheet.
>
> CTRL+ALT+F9 calculates all worksheets
>   in all open workbooks, regardless of
>   whether they have changed since the
>   last calculation.
>
> CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F9 rechecks dependent
>   formulas, and then calculates all
>   cells in all open workbooks, including
>   cells not marked as needing to be
>   calculated.

source: [microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx#BM3)

Comment: I knew there was a function like this, but the <kbd>F1</kbd> Help didn't well.. help.